# image to grow outside Javafx gridpane cell

Tags: image, grid, javafx-2

I would like to add an image to javafx2 gridpane as per code below, however I would like this image to not be restricted inside its cell. I would like the image to basically flow outside the cell.

```
     GridPane moon_pane = new GridPane();
        moon_pane.setId("prayertime_pane");
        moon_pane.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        moon_pane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        moon_pane.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
        moon_pane.setVgap(10);
        moon_pane.setHgap(10);


        Text moon_phase_text = new Text("60% full");
        moon_phase_text.setId("prayer-text-english");
        moon_pane.setHalignment(moon_phase_text,HPos.LEFT);
        moon_pane.setValignment(moon_phase_text,VPos.CENTER);
        moon_pane.setConstraints(moon_phase_text, 0, 0);
        moon_pane.getChildren().add(moon_phase_text);

        ImageView Moon_img = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Images/Full_Moon.png")));
//        moon_pane.setHalignment(Moon_img,HPos.CENTER);
//        moon_pane.setValignment(Moon_img,VPos.CENTER);      
        Moon_img.setFitWidth(100);
        Moon_img.setFitHeight(100);
        moon_pane.add(Moon_img, 1, 0);

        Text next_moon_text = new Text("13/02");
        next_moon_text.setId("prayer-text-english");
        moon_pane.setHalignment(next_moon_text,HPos.LEFT);
        moon_pane.setValignment(next_moon_text,VPos.CENTER);
        moon_pane.setConstraints(next_moon_text, 2, 0);
        moon_pane.getChildren().add(next_moon_text);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try increasing the scale on the ImageView node. I believe scaling happens separately from layout/resizing.